# only allow children of a specific type in a react component

Tags: validation, reactjs

I have a `Card` component and a `CardGroup` component, and I'd like to throw an error when `CardGroup` has children that aren't `Card` components. Is this possible, or am I trying to solve the wrong problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the displayName for each child, accessed via type:

```
for (child in this.props.children){
  if (this.props.children[child].type.displayName != 'Card'){
    console.log("Warning CardGroup has children that aren't Card components");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Make sure to check whether the current environment is development or production. propTypes validation is not triggered in production for performance. Using customProp in propTypes will be helpful.

Comment: You shouldn't do this because `props.children` is an [opaque data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type). Better use `React.Children` utilities as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36424582/1385678).

Comment: Keep in mind though, using things like Uglify will break this

Comment: @MoeSattler is that true? I thought uglify would leave strings like that alone, because it can't know for certain whether they're being used elsewhere or not..

Comment: The string won't change, but the Component's name might.

Comment: As @RyanRho pointed out this can cause issue when running React in production mode. Instead I added a defaultProp to the child component e.g `static defaultProps = { isCard: true}` and then checked for this e.g `if (!this.props.children[child].props.isCard) { ... }`

Comment: That "helped me", but I used `name` instead of `displayName` (this last one doesn't worked for me)

Comment: Never use the displayName since in production it might be stripped out!

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `child.type.prototype instanceof Card` instead? Then minification/uglifying shouldn't cause an issue.

Comment: Related: [How to get children type in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212960/how-to-get-children-type-in-react) (`name` might be a better option than `displayName`)

Answer (score 68):

For React 0.14+ and using ES6 classes, the solution will look like:

```js
class CardGroup extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    )
  }
}
CardGroup.propTypes = {
  children: function (props, propName, componentName) {
    const prop = props[propName]

    let error = null
    React.Children.forEach(prop, function (child) {
      if (child.type !== Card) {
        error = new Error('`' + componentName + '` children should be of type `Card`.');
      }
    })
    return error
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but ```child.type === Card``` isn't working in my setup. However I got it working by using ```child.type.prototype instanceof Card```. My React version is 15.5.4

Comment: why not just throw it then and there, instead of returning an Error value.

Comment: @user2167582 Because that's the expected API for prop validation functions. [Official docs](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/README.md) include the following comment in example code:
_You can also specify a custom validator. It should return an Error object if the validation fails. Don't `console.warn` or throw, as this won't work inside `oneOfType`_.

Comment: Where's the docs of `child.type`? Can someone send link it please?

Comment: this worked for me

React.Children.forEach(props[propName], function (child) {
          if (child.type && child.type.name !== 'Card') {
            error = new Error('Blabla ´' + componentName + ' some error');
          }
        })

Comment: @VeikkoKarsikko That's the only thing that worked for me. Thank you! This should be an answer, rather than a comment

Comment: @nerdess using child.type.name is not going to work in the minified production build...!

Comment: @VeikkoKarsikko ```instanceof``` should work when you're using class components, but will not when you're using function components. In the case of the latter, use the ```child.type === Card``` comparison.

Comment: Worth noting that `React.Children` iterates only through top-level children, so if you want to check the type of a child, you'll need to do so with `child.props.children`.

Comment: I'm on an MDX setup and only way I got it working was `child.props.mdxType === 'TabPanel'`

Answer (score 17):

For those using a TypeScript version.
You can filter/modify components like this:

```
this.modifiedChildren = React.Children.map(children, child => {
            if (React.isValidElement(child) && (child as React.ReactElement<any>).type === Card) {
                let modifiedChild = child as React.ReactElement<any>;
                // Modifying here
                return modifiedChild;
            }
            // Returning other components / string.
            // Delete next line in case you dont need them.
            return child;
        });
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use a custom propType function to validate children, since children are just props. I also wrote an [article](http://www.mattzabriskie.com/blog/react-validating-children) on this, if you want more details.

```js
var CardGroup = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    children: function (props, propName, componentName) {
      var error;
      var prop = props[propName];

      React.Children.forEach(prop, function (child) {
        if (child.type.displayName !== 'Card') {
          error = new Error(
            '`' + componentName + '` only accepts children of type `Card`.'
          );
        }
      });

      return error;
    }
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this syntax still valid with ES2015 and React 0.14.x+?

Comment: Thanks, @DiegoV. I think you can also declare `static propTypes = {}` in the class definition.

Comment: I like that syntax too but class properties are still just a proposal for ES7. Personally I'll wait to see if it gets standardized :)

Comment: ```child.type.displayName``` isn't working after obfuscation

Answer (score 11):

Use the `React.Children.forEach` method to iterate over the children and use the `name` property to check the type:

```
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child) => {
    if (child.type.name !== Card.name) {
        console.error("Only card components allowed as children.");
    }
}
```

I recommend to use `Card.name` instead of `'Card'` string for better maintenance and stability in respect to *uglify*.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Comment: Working only if I change name to displayName

**if (child.type.displayName !== Card.name)**

Answer (score 6):

One has to use "React.isValidElement(child)" along with "child.type" if one is working with Typescript in order to avoid type mismatch errors.

```
React.Children.forEach(props.children, (child, index) => {
  if (React.isValidElement(child) && child.type !== Card) {
    error = new Error(
      '`' + componentName + '` only accepts children of type `Card`.'
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I have an error with this code: [ts] This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string | ComponentClass<{}, any> | StatelessComponent<{}>' and 'typeof MyChildClass' have no overlap. [2367]

Answer (score 5):

You can add a prop to your `Card` component and then check for this prop in your `CardGroup` component. This is the safest way to achieve this in React.

This prop can be added as a defaultProp so it's always there.

```
class Card extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    isCard: true,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>A Card</div>
    )
  }
}

class CardGroup extends Component {

  render() {
    for (child in this.props.children) {
      if (!this.props.children[child].props.isCard){
        console.error("Warning CardGroup has a child which isn't a Card component");
      }
    }

    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Checking for whether the Card component is indeed a Card component by using `type` or `displayName` is not safe as it may not work during production use as indicated here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6167#issuecomment-191243709

Comment: This seems to be the only way I can get this working in a **production build**. I have a component that clones its children while adding extra props only to those of a certain type.

Answer (score 4):

I made a custom PropType for this that I call `equalTo`. You can use it like this...

```js
class MyChildComponent extends React.Component { ... }

class MyParentComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.equalTo(MyChildComponent))
  }
}
```

Now, `MyParentComponent` only accepts children that are `MyChildComponent`. You can check for html elements like this...

```js
PropTypes.equalTo('h1')
PropTypes.equalTo('div')
PropTypes.equalTo('img')
...
```

Here is the implementation...

```js
React.PropTypes.equalTo = function (component) {
  return function validate(propValue, key, componentName, location, propFullName) {
    const prop = propValue[key]
    if (prop.type !== component) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propFullName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
  };
}
```

You could easily extend this to accept one of many possible types. Maybe something like...

```js
React.PropTypes.equalToOneOf = function (arrayOfAcceptedComponents) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
static propTypes = {

  children : (props, propName, componentName) => {
              const prop = props[propName];
              return React.Children
                       .toArray(prop)
                       .find(child => child.type !== Card) && new Error(`${componentName} only accepts "<Card />" elements`);
  },

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I published the package that allows to validate the types of React elements https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-element-proptypes :

```
const ElementPropTypes = require('react-element-proptypes');

const Modal = ({ header, items }) => (
    <div>
        <div>{header}</div>
        <div>{items}</div>
    </div>
);

Modal.propTypes = {
    header: ElementPropTypes.elementOfType(Header).isRequired,
    items: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(ElementPropTypes.elementOfType(Item))
};

// render Modal 
React.render(
    <Modal
       header={<Header title="This is modal" />}
       items={[
           <Item/>,
           <Item/>,
           <Item/>
       ]}
    />,
    rootElement
);
```

Answer (score 3):

To validate correct children component i combine the use of [react children foreach](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenforeach) and the [Custom validation proptypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes), so at the end you can have the following:

```
HouseComponent.propTypes = {
children: PropTypes.oneOfType([(props, propName, componentName) => {
    let error = null;
    const validInputs = [
    'Mother',
    'Girlfried',
    'Friends',
    'Dogs'
    ];
    // Validate the valid inputs components allowed.
    React.Children.forEach(props[propName], (child) => {
            if (!validInputs.includes(child.type.name)) {
                error = new Error(componentName.concat(
                ' children should be one of the type:'
                    .concat(validInputs.toString())
            ));
        }
    });
    return error;
    }]).isRequired
};
```

As you can see is having and array with the name of the correct type.

On the other hand there is also a function called componentWithName from the airbnb/prop-types library that helps to have the same result.
[Here you can see more details](https://github.com/airbnb/prop-types)

```
HouseComponent.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        componentWithName('SegmentedControl'),
        componentWithName('FormText'),
        componentWithName('FormTextarea'),
        componentWithName('FormSelect')
    ]).isRequired
};
```

Hope this help some one :)

Answer (score 3):

Considered multiple proposed approaches, but they all turned out to be either unreliable or overcomplicated to serve as a boilerplate. Settled on the following implementation.

```js
class Card extends Component {
  // ...
}

class CardGroup extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      (propValue, key, componentName) => (propValue[key].type !== Card)
        ? new Error(`${componentName} only accepts children of type ${Card.name}.`)
        : null
    )
  }
  // ...
}
```

Here're the key ideas:

1. Utilize the built-in `PropTypes.arrayOf()` instead of looping over children
2. Check the child type via `propValue[key].type !== Card` in a custom validator
3. Use variable substitution `${Card.name}` to not hard-code the type name

Library [react-element-proptypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-element-proptypes) implements this in `ElementPropTypes.elementOfType()`:

```js
import ElementPropTypes from "react-element-proptypes";

class CardGroup extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.arrayOf(ElementPropTypes.elementOfType(Card))
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy, production friendly check.  At the top of your CardGroup component:

```
const cardType = (<Card />).type;
```

Then, when iterating over the children:

```
React.children.map(child => child.type === cardType ? child : null);
```

The nice thing about this check is that it will also work with library components/sub-components that don't expose the necessary classes to make an `instanceof` check work.

Comment: `(<Card />).type` is equivalent to `Card`, i.e. the validation is simply `child.type === Card`

Answer (score 0):

Assert the type:

```
props.children.forEach(child =>
  console.assert(
    child.type.name == "CanvasItem",
    "CanvasScroll can only have CanvasItem component as children."
  )
)
```

Comment: It's unreliable to iterate over the children prop assuming it's an array. It very well can be null or a single node. React provides handy utilities for handling children, such as React.Children.forEach(). See the official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Answer (score 0):

Related to this post, I figured out a similar problem I had. I needed to throw an error if a child was one of many icons in a Tooltip component.

// icons/index.ts

```
export {default as AddIcon} from './AddIcon';
export {default as SubIcon} from './SubIcon';
...
```

// components/Tooltip.tsx

```
import { Children, cloneElement, isValidElement } from 'react';
import * as AllIcons from 'common/icons';
...
const Tooltip = ({children, ...rest}) => {
   Children.forEach(children, child => {
      // ** Inspired from this post
      const reactNodeIsOfIconType = (node, allIcons) => {
         const iconTypes = Object.values(allIcons);
         return iconTypes.some(type => typeof node === 'object' && node !== null && node.type === type);
      };
    
      console.assert(!reactNodeIsOfIconType(child, AllIcons),'Use  some other component instead...')
   })
   ...
   return Children.map(children, child => {
      if (isValidElement(child) {
         return cloneElement(child, ...rest);
      }
      return null;
   });
}
```