# How to get children type in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make my own `Tabs` component, so that I can use tabs in my app. However I seem to be having issues trying to extract the child components I need by type.

```
import React from 'react'

export class Tabs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let children = this.props.children
    let tablinks = React.Children.map(children, x => {
      console.log(x.type.displayName) // Always undefined
      if (x.type.displayName == 'Tab Link') {
        return x
      }
    })

    return (
      <div className="tabs"></div>
    )
  }
}

export class TabLink extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.displayName = 'Tab Link'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tab-link"></div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

```
<Tabs>
    <TabLink path="tab1">Test</TabLink>
    <TabLink path="tab2">Test2</TabLink>
</Tabs>
```

My `console.log` never returns "Tab Link", it always returns `undefined`, why?

Comment: Did you mean to have TabLink extend Tabs? Right now it's just a sibling as it extends React.Component.

Comment: @Jecoms Wait, I have to extend Tabs? How would that work? Doesn't it need to extend React.Component to work?

Comment: I misunderstood your intent. I feel like x.type is the problem, but I'd have to research further.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As an alternative you could use

```
console.log(x.type.name) // this would be 'TabLink'
```

You don't need to explicitly define displayName in this case.

https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/u1twznw7/1/

Answer (score 3):

It's `undefined` because `displayName` should be a `static` property.

```
class TabLink extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tab-link"></div>
    )
  }
} 
TabLink.displayName = 'Tab Link'
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/54399/) (check the console)

Comment: Dunno about this. Our team prefers encapsulation with `static get displayName() {return "blah"}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the already defined `name` property:

```
if (x.type.name === TabLink.name) {
    return x
}
```

I recommend to use `TabLink.name` instead of `'TabLink'` string for better maintenance.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why does your `Tabs` component need to know how to render each children.

You could have a specific component for each type of tab, with their own styles and with 2 props: `isSelected` and `onSelect`.

Then the `Tabs` would only:

1. Render its children, inline, with the correct space among them ("display:flex" with column-gap)
2. Control the tab selection, by keeping the state of the selected tab and handling the `onSelect` of each tab (to update the selectedTab state and to pass true in the `isSelected` prop of the correct tab)