# ReactJs: What should the PropTypes be for this.props.children?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-proptypes

Given a simple component that renders its children:

```
class ContainerComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContainerComponent;
```

**Question: What should the propType of the children prop be?**

When I set it as an object, it fails when I use the component with multiple children:

```
<ContainerComponent>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</ContainerComponent>
```

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array`
>   supplied to `ContainerComponent`, expected `object`.

If I set it as an array, it will fail if I give it only one child, i.e.:

```
<ContainerComponent>
  <div>1</div>
</ContainerComponent>
```

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop children of type object
>   supplied to ContainerComponent, expected array.

Please advise, should I just not bother doing a propTypes check for children elements?

Comment: You probably want `node`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [only allow children of a specific type in a react component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366077/only-allow-children-of-a-specific-type-in-a-react-component)

Comment: Please see my answer below that describes more options, but, if you are looking for component child then it's PropTypes.element. PropTypes.node describes anything that can be rendered - strings, numbers, elements or an array of these things. If this suits you then this is the way.

Answer (score 553, accepted):

Try something like this utilizing `oneOfType` or `PropTypes.node`

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

...

static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
        PropTypes.node
    ]).isRequired
}
```

or

```
static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it fails with the same error in the single child case: "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object`...expected an array."

Comment: That worked!  The simplest solution is `children: PropTypes.node`, that worked for both cases.  Thanks for the suggestions =)

Comment: The only thing that would make this answer clearer would be if you included a note similar to @ggilberth 's answer to explain that `React.PropTypes.node` describes any renderable object.

Comment: There's no need for array, just `PropTypes.node`. That handles the following correcting: nothing, string, single element, several elements, fragment, component.

Comment: I need to hang this answer somewhere on the wall of my room. I keep coming back here over and over again. :)

Answer (score 62):

For me it depends on the component. If you know what you need it to be populated with then you should try to specify exclusively, or multiple types using:

```
PropTypes.oneOfType
```

If you want to refer to a React component then you will be looking for

```
PropTypes.element
```

Although,

```
PropTypes.node
```

describes anything that can be rendered - strings, numbers, elements or an array of these things. If this suits you then this is the way.

With *very* generic components, who can have many types of children, you can also use the below. However I wouldn't recommend it. As mentioned in the comments below, it does somewhat defeat the point of using `PropTypes` and there are usually other ways to specify what your component requires. Also bare in mind that eslint and ts may (probably) not be happy with this lack of specificity:

```
PropTypes.any
```

Comment: `Proptypes.any` is too common type. Eslint is not happy with that.

Comment: `Proptypes.any` would also mean `object` and the app may crash if you pass an `object`.

Comment: If you're going to use `any`, you should just save yourself the time of using propTypes at all.

Answer (score 37):

[The PropTypes documentation](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blame/master/README.md#L77) has the following

```
// Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array
// (or fragment) containing these types.
optionalNode: PropTypes.node,
```

So, you can use `PropTypes.node` to check for objects or arrays of objects

```
static propTypes = {
   children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score 19):

The answers here don't seem to quite cover checking the children exactly. `node` and `object` are too permissive, I wanted to check the exact element. Here is what I ended up using:

- Use `oneOfType([])` to allow for single or array of children
- Use `shape` and `arrayOf(shape({}))` for single and array of children, respectively
- Use `oneOf` for the child element itself

In the end, something like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'

children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.shape({
    type: PropTypes.oneOf([MyComponent]),
  }),
  PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      type: PropTypes.oneOf([MyComponent]),
    })
  ),
]).isRequired
```

This issue helped me figure this out more clearly: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2979

Answer (score 6):

If you want to match exactly a component type, check this

```
MenuPrimary.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(MenuPrimaryItem),
    PropTypes.objectOf(MenuPrimaryItem)
  ])
}
```

If you want to match exactly some component types, check this

```
const HeaderTypes = [
  PropTypes.objectOf(MenuPrimary),
  PropTypes.objectOf(UserInfo)
]

Header.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([...HeaderTypes])),
    ...HeaderTypes
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to include render prop components:

```
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
    PropTypes.node,
    PropTypes.func
  ])
```

Comment: `optionalElement: PropTypes.element` is great also for passing...a React element, e.g. a React component that you create.

Answer (score 3):

Try a custom propTypes :

```
 const  childrenPropTypeLogic = (props, propName, componentName) => {
          const prop = props[propName];
          return React.Children
                   .toArray(prop)
                   .find(child => child.type !== 'div') && new Error(`${componentName} only accepts "div" elements`);
 };


static propTypes = {

   children : childrenPropTypeLogic

}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/9h69tt3o/)

```js
const {Component, PropTypes} = React;

 const  childrenPropTypeLogic = (props, propName, componentName) => {
             var error;
          var prop = props[propName];
    
          React.Children.forEach(prop, function (child) {
            if (child.type !== 'div') {
              error = new Error(
                '`' + componentName + '` only accepts children of type `div`.'
              );
            }
          });
    
          return error;
    };
    
  

class ContainerComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: childrenPropTypeLogic,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}



class App extends Component {
   render(){
    return (
    <ContainerComponent>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
      </ContainerComponent>
    )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector('section'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<section />
```

Answer (score 1):

Accoriding to [propTypes documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#requiring-single-child) `element` is used for React element, and children is one of them:

```
// A React element.
optionalElement: PropTypes.element,
```

Then you can combine it with `arrayOf`

Component.propTypes = {
children: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element).isRequired,
};

Then it will require at least one `children`.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li>
                <a href={this.props.href}>{this.props.children}</a>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

MenuItem.defaultProps = {
    href: "/",
    children: "Main page"
};

MenuItem.propTypes = {
    href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default MenuItem;
```

Picture: Shows you error in console if the expected type is different

[image: Picture: Shows you error in console if the expected type is different]