# How i can destructuring {this.props.children}?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, destructuring

I want to add a background to my mobile app but when i use  "this.props.children"
eslint say me "Must use destructuring props assignment". Why i can destructuring this props ?

This my code ,

```html
export default class WallPaper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={backgroundimg}
        imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

when i use this code

```html
export default class WallPaper extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={backgroundimg}
        imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        {children}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

i have this error "'children' is missing in props validation"
[image: error]

when i use this code ,

```html
export default class WallPaper extends Component {
  render() {
     (this.props) => {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={backgroundimg}
        imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        {props.children}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
    }
  }
}
```

i have this error, 
[image]

thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md explains this rule better.

Comment: Also this is a linter rule so not technically an error so unless you're working in a team that is enforcing a specific rule set then you should modify the rules to ones you are most comfortable with working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the following to destructure `children` from `this.props`:

```
export default class WallPaper extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={backgroundimg}
        imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        {children}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

It looks like your project may require propTypes for this component. Try the following to add a `children` prop type. Note, you will need to install package [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types):

```
// ... 
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class WallPaper extends Component {      
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={backgroundimg}
        imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        {children}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

WallPaper.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node // or PropTypes.node.isRequired to make it required
};

export default WallPaper;
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I have already tried this method but I get the error "'children' is missing in props validation"

Comment: @MichelMelhem `const { children } = this.props;` would be exactly how you achieve destructuring. If you have PropTypes validations on component `WallPaper`, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122522/reactjs-what-should-the-proptypes-be-for-this-props-children) for an approach to children PropTypes validation. Try though first removing propTypes temporarily to see if the linting error via this destructuring assignment is resolved. If you continue to have issues after adding children to propTypes validation, share your propTypes code for additional support. Thanks!

Comment: Does your project require that each component has propTypes? If so, go ahead and please add propTypes to this component.

Answer (score 11):

The answers are missing for functional component cases.
children is just a prop passed to the component. In order to use it like you are using props.url you need to add it to that list so it can be "pulled out" of the props object.

```
export const Welcome = ({name, hero, children}) => {
        return (
        <div>
           <h1> Class Component with {name} as {hero} </h1>
            {children}
        </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
export default class WallPaper extends Component {
  render() {
     (this.props) => {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={backgroundimg}
        imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        {props.children}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When i use you code i have an Parsing error: Unexpected token

  15 |   render() {
  16 |     props => (
> 17 |       return (
     |       ^
  18 |       <ImageBackground
  19 |         source={backgroundimg}
  20 |         imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [linting rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md).

You can turn off rule if you don't want destructing.

If you want than you can do it like this.

```
export default class WallPaper extends Component {
  render() {
  const {children} = this.props
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={backgroundimg}
        imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.9 }}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @MichelMelhem what ?? can you write in English ? can't understand what you have written ?

Comment: excuse me it was a fail this is the message:

yes i know i can disable this rule but if this rule exists it's probably a good reason

Answer (score 1):

and for the class component:

```
export class Welcome extends Component {
    render(){
        const {name, hero, children} = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> Class Component with {name} as {hero} </h1>
                {children}
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```