# React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child Stuck

Tags: reactjs, maps, react-leaflet

Get an error Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
Really stuck, Anybody help?

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(this.props.url).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data._embedded.districts;
      this.setState({ data });
      console.log(this.state.data);
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log("render");
    if (this.props.terr === "districts") {
      return (
        <FeatureGroup>
          {this.state.data.map((data) => {
            return (
              <GeoJSON
                key={data.name}
                data={data.geometry}
                style={this.myStyle}
              >
                <Popup>{data.name}</Popup>
              </GeoJSON>
            );
          })}
        </FeatureGroup>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `FeatureGroup`? Does it have `prop-types`? Specifically `prop-types` that places restrictions on prop `children`? You can consider reviewing the following answer in terms of how to use prop types for prop `children`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42122662/5059657

Answer (score 1):

I got same error. In my case there was an empty space inside  component with  tag. Empty space {""} inside  was considered another component and since <Link
accepts only one component I got that error.

```
 <Link href="/"> {" "} // I removed empty space
    <a className="navbar-brand">GitTix</a>
  </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the code it is hard to tell. I have a tingling that your this.state.data is null or empty in your constructor and the first time you are trying to render your map function isn't returning any data.  componentDidMount will run after it has already been rendered.

try checking to see if there is data in your data first.

```
{this.state.data.length && <FeatureGroup>
      {this.state.data.map((data) => {
        return (
          <GeoJSON
            key={data.name}
            data={data.geometry}
            style={this.myStyle}
          >
            <Popup>{data.name}</Popup>
          </GeoJSON>
        );
      })}
    </FeatureGroup>}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, `FeatureGroup` is expecting a single element as a child. Currently you have one to many elements given the `Array.prototype.map` you are using to process an array and generate elements. Likely this is coming from [prop-types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) on `FeatureGroup` that specify how many children are allowed. This is not uncommon, elements like `Provider` from `react-redux` expect a single child. At minimum wrap the output of the `Array.prototype.map` with an element:

```
<FeatureGroup>
  <div>
    {this.state.data.map((data) => {
      return (
        <GeoJSON
          key={data.name}
          data={data.geometry}
          style={this.myStyle}
        >
          <Popup>{data.name}</Popup>
        </GeoJSON>
      );
    })}
  </div>
</FeatureGroup>
```

Or you can use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
<FeatureGroup>
  <React.Fragment>
    {this.state.data.map((data) => {
      return (
        <GeoJSON
          key={data.name}
          data={data.geometry}
          style={this.myStyle}
        >
          <Popup>{data.name}</Popup>
        </GeoJSON>
      );
    })}
  </React.Fragment>
</FeatureGroup>
```

Hopefully that helps!