# How to restrict the number of child in a component to only one in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a component that accepts children, what I want to do is limit the number of children to only one, I want the child to be a single view or single text in react native

Comment: We would appreciate if you give more info on this, for starters you can add code which you have tried so far.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) API, specifically `React.Children.only`.

I believe the proper syntax is:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return React.Children.only(this.props.children)()
  }
}
```

This will verify that there is only one child, and return that child, or throw an error if there is more than one child.

You can also use `PropTypes`

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const children = this.props.children
    return (
      <>
        {children}
      </>
    )
  }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}
```

If you would further like to enforce that your child is only a `Text` or `View` instance, you can write a custom [`PropTypes` validator](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), here is an [example on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36424582/8378419)

Comment: Thank your for your support, I used proptype menu worked fine for me :)