# React.cloneElement returning double elements when trying to validate a child element

Tags: reactjs, validation, clone-element

I'm trying to pass props from Parent ("Section") element to all Children elements while trying to make sure that only "Block" elements can be used as children. It works fine when I use React.cloneElement the following way:

```
const Blocks = React.Children.map(children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        type: this.props.type,
      });
    });
```

But when add the validation the following way:

```
const Blocks = React.Children.map(children, child => {
      if (child instanceof Block) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          ...this.props,
        });
      } else {
        console.log('not a block');
        console.log(child);
      }
    });
```

No content shows up at all. But when I use the validation code the following way:

```
const Blocks = React.Children.map(children, child => {
      if (child instanceof Block) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          ...this.props,
        });
      } else {
        console.log('not a block');
        console.log(child);
      }
    });
```

But when I do it the following way, all elements show up double/twice:

```
const Blocks = React.Children.map(children, child => {
  if (child.type === Block) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      ...this.props,
    });
  } else {
    console.log('not a block');
    console.log(child);
  }
});
```

As this output image:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNsBg.jpg)

I'm pretty new to this. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366077/only-allow-children-of-a-specific-type-in-a-react-component/36424582  check this once

Comment: Thanx but that didn't work. Actually, my issue is not that I can't validate a child, That part is working fine, but the issue is that when I'm getting the return, it's giving me back every element twice. Just as the screenshot I've provided above.

Comment: can you make a codepen /  stackblitz on this

Comment: I quickly test out your code in a minimal setting & [it works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0rlr878wj). Perhaps the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thanx. Your example is very helpful ... that works for me if I use specific props (like, type: this.props.type etc.), but as soon as I use `...this.props` everything doubles up again ...