# How to solve type issue when implementing React children components to have only specific components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a kind of React children components validation to have only specific components but facing an issue with type.

Please check out my code below:

```
// a component needs the validation

import { Children, FunctionComponent, isValidElement } from 'react';
import { AccordionProps } from '@components/old/signup/organisms/accordion/interfaces';
import CheckFormField from '@components/old/signup/organisms/checkFormField';
import AccordionHeader from '@components/old/signup/organisms/accordionHeader';


const Accordion: FunctionComponent<AccordionProps> = ({ children }) => {
                                                                                             
const allowedComponents = [CheckFormField, AccordionHeader]; // these can only be children

Children.map(children, (child) => {
    const childType = isValidElement(child) && child.type;
    if (!allowedComponents.includes(childType)) { // here comes type error to use includes method
      throw new Error('Error message..');
    }
  });
                            :
                            :
return (
  <div>{children}</div>
);
```

The type error from above code:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'string | false | JSXElementConstructor<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionComponent<CheckFormFiledProps> | FunctionComponent<AccordionHeaderProps>'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<CheckFormFiledProps> | FunctionComponent<AccordionHeaderProps>'.`

and the props that I defined below:

```
// interfaces.ts

export interface AccordionProps {
  children: ReactElement<any> | ReactElement[];
}
```

I suspect that the children prop above isn't probably proper type to make it but no luck to search it so far.

references:

[only allow children of a specific type in a react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366077/only-allow-children-of-a-specific-type-in-a-react-component)

[Only allow specific components as children in React and Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627929/only-allow-specific-components-as-children-in-react-and-typescript)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself the code below with no interface change makes it work.

```
import {Children, FunctionComponent, isValidElement} from 'react'
                                 :
                                 :
Children.map(children, (child) => {
    const childType = isValidElement(child) && child.type;
    if (!allowedComponents.includes(childType) as FunctionComponent<any>) { // as FunctionComponent<any> shuts the type error complaining
      throw new Error('Error message..');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution to this is to pass the target children components to the parent component **via component properties, instead of classic `children`**. Let's call the child components property `Components`, to distinguish from the standard `children`.

So here is how the child component array is validated (by the TypeScript itself) and rendered via the `Main` component:

```js
// Main.tsx

import ValidChildOne from './ValidChildOne';
import ValidChildTwo from './ValidChildTwo';

// declaring what is allowed as children
type AllowedChild = typeof ValidChildOne | typeof ValidChildTwo;

interface MainProps {
  Components: AllowedChild[];  // array
}

export default function Main({ Components }: MainProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Main</h1>
      {
        Components.map((Child, index) => <Child key={index} />)
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

Respectively, here is how the `Main` component (and its props) is applied:

```js
// App.tsx

import Main from './Main';
import ValidChildOne from './ValidChildOne';
import ValidChildTwo from './ValidChildTwo';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Main Components={[ValidChildOne, ValidChildTwo]} />
  );
}
```

Finally, the child components' code for reference:

```js
// ValidChildOne.tsx

export default function ValidChildOne() {
  return <h2>ValidChildOne</h2>;
}
```

```js
// ValidChildTwo.tsx

export default function ValidChildTwo() {
  return <h2>ValidChildTwo</h2>;
}
```

Comment: Good but not that I am looking for as ultimately I wanted to make it as utility function to apply it for components which need validation.