# React + Typescript: Expecting children component with specific props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a component that requires at least two specific child components to be used.

These two components are exported as dot notations from the main component and include `defaultProps` to identify them in the main component:

```
export interface ComponentPropsInterface {
  children: React.ReactChild;
}

const Component = ({ children }: ComponentPropsInterface ): JSX.Element => {
  const childrenArray = React.Children.toArray(children);
  return (
    <>
        {
          // Find a component with the wanted prop and place it in a specific place
          childrenArray.filter(
            (child) =>
              child.props.__TYPE === 'Trigger'
          )[0]
        }
    </>
  );
};

const Trigger = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactChild;
  __TYPE?: string;
}) => <>{children}</>;

// Prop is assigned here automatically
Trigger.defaultProps = {
  __TYPE: 'Trigger',
};

// Export as dot notation
Popover.Trigger = Trigger;

// Export component
export default Component;
```

In the above I'm checking if `Component` has children, which is *okay*, but it's not failproof.

I would like to ensure `children` has a at least one `child` with the `__TYPE === 'Trigger'` prop.

Is there any way to do this directly from Typescript? Or should I throw an error if the child component I need isn't present?

EDIT: For precision's sake, I'd like the error to appear in the IDE on the parent `<Component/>` when it is used without one of the required children.

Comment: I'm not going to answer since I haven't checked this for a few months, and it might have changed, but it used to be the case that this was not possible. This question gives the method that 'should' work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627929/only-allow-specific-components-as-children-in-react-and-typescript but the typescript compiler does not have the ability do differentiate between JSX Elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if you are using typescript and you want to use `Array.prototype.filter` - use custom typeguard as a filter predicate:

```js
import React from 'react'

export interface ComponentPropsInterface {
  children: React.ReactElement<{ __TYPE: string }>[];
}

const predicate = (child: React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal):
  child is React.ReactElement<{ __TYPE: 'Trigger' }> =>
  React.isValidElement(child) ? child.props.__TYPE === 'Trigger' : false

const Component = ({ children }: ComponentPropsInterface): JSX.Element => (
  <>
    {
      // Find a component with the wanted prop and place it in a specific place
      React.Children.toArray(children).filter(predicate)[0]
    }
  </>
)

const Trigger = (props: {
  __TYPE: string;
}) => <div></div>;

const Invalid: React.FC<{ label: string }> = ({ label }) => {
  return <div>{label}</div>;
};


const Test = () =>
  React.createElement(Component, {
    children: [
      React.createElement(Invalid, { label: "d" }), // error
      React.createElement(Trigger, { __TYPE: 'Trigger' }), // ok
    ],
  })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-utvL56H5ooEnoy4DY0gA3YI2bm14LRUjxFNwcQ1q7FWYGJocZaagBGSFUXh8-n2mfsw9HQQrBzzRBgAFcoPQq02ZLPVIEG02yy3W-DU0gkrk8gvjvoDGgiJkkPTGHlcWKYAAaOB5hQYzR8XShLGCgnHeqBME+9ydt2n4zigI5jnAABE6iIfOn68nAzA4FAQG9qBD4QXkaY7FAMH5msujAlsJF7OW6F8hAADWsbhO+4zluQQA)
Also, in order to get `props` you need to check if element is valid `React.isValidElement`

AFAIK, it is possible to infer type of child components only with native react syntax `createElement`, because this method has a lot of overloads. `jsx` syntax, from the other side, infers every element to `JSX.Element`

Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/typed-react-children)

Comment: Thank you for improving my code! This is a lot better logic wise, but it still doesn't throw an error if the required child isn't used.

Comment: I have added a fallbck. I don't think it is good idea to throw any error inside react component

Comment: I tested https://stackoverflow.com/a/57628053/8685682 and adding `children: Array<React.ReactElement<TriggerPropsInterface>>` to check the type of the child seems to work. If you want to add it to your answer I can mark it as accepted 

Comment: @Eight just curious, does my solution work? Because I did not test it in runtime . Since you already added a link to example which is works for you I don't think it worth adding to my answer. Feel free to not accept my answer. Just don't want to duplicate anything

Comment: Your answer isn't exactly the answer to the question as it just makes the `filter` more precise. The link actually throws a typescript error unless a child of type is passed which is closer to the initial question.

Up to you honestly, I can self answer if you prefer.

Comment: SUre, maybe I just did not understand the question. No problem. Please answer, I will upvote your answer

Comment: Upon further inspection the other answer didn't work  Must've done something wrong. Back to square one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236940/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-eight).