# How can I fix the type of children being passed to my functional component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React/Typescript project, I need a Component, lets call that A (it is a functional component), which is simply a wrapper component and needs to accept and display two components that I have made (lets call them B and C) so that A can be used as the following:

```
<A>
 <B/>
 <C/>
</A>
```

I need to ensure that only B and C are passed as children of A and nothing else.

How can I achieve this in typescript?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe?

```
interface AppProps {
  children: [React.ReactNode, React.ReactNode];
}
```

If you want to go further to check what those types are that maybe [trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627929/only-allow-specific-components-as-children-in-react-and-typescript), if possible at all.

Comment: Uhh, yeah i was hoping to strongly type the children to be of a specific type. For example: children: ReactElement<typeof B | typeof C>

This doesn't really work tho and passing anything other than B or C will still work (also mentioned in the link you've shared).