# how to allow only define type to be children component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a component library. I would like to had a way to just allow some component to be child of a parent.

For example:

```
export default function InputWrapperComponent({children}:{children:JSX.Element}){return {children}}
```

I would like this wrapper to take only the CurrencyInput and TextInput component as children. How can I make it possible. (if possible with generic types)

Comment: You could use `React.ComponentType` to type it: `children: React.ComponentType<CurrencyInput> | React.ComponentType<TextInput>`

Comment: @KajDeMuynck This is not possible: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/advanced/patterns_by_usecase#what-you-cannot-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only allow specific components as children in React and Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627929/only-allow-specific-components-as-children-in-react-and-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible in React with TypeScript. For an explanation of why and what you can do instead, see here: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/advanced/patterns_by_usecase#typing-children