# Wrap components inside a wrapper component conditionally in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dot-notation

I am working on a generic component which has some sub-components that are wrapped into the main component like this:

```
<Main>
    <Main.First />
    <Main.Second />
    <Main.Third />
</Main>
```

The main point here is that I want to prevent any component which is not Main. from being wrapped into the  component so for instance:

```
<Main>
  <span>any random text</span>
</Main>
```

This should return an error. I am using react.cloneElement to render the child components of the Main component and I want to add this condition. Here is how I loop over it

```
React.Children.toArray(children).map(child => child)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A TypeScript approach to this problem: [Only allow specific components as children in React and Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627929/only-allow-specific-components-as-children-in-react-and-typescript) And an old but possibly useful JS version: [Only allow children of a specific type in a react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366077/only-allow-children-of-a-specific-type-in-a-react-component)