# React propTypes for specific children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a function component like so:

`const Foo = () => <div>Hello world</div>;`

Now I have another component that accepts children but should be restricted to 1 or more of the `Foo` component specifically (no other components allowed).

`const Bar = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;`

How do I set `propTypes` on `Bar` to achieve this validation?

```
Bar.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOf([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
    PropTypes.node,
  ]);
};
```

The above is too loose because it will let any component type as children. How do I limit it to only allow `Foo`?

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366077/only-allow-children-of-a-specific-type-in-a-react-component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PropTypes.shape`

```
Bar.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.shape({
      type: PropTypes.oneOf([Foo]),
    }),
    PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        type: PropTypes.oneOf([Foo]),
      })
    ),
  ]).isRequired
};
```