# Only allow certain component as children (React, TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, children

This question is asked multiple times and I went through answers for hours. However, I am unable to get my code to work. Here is the problem.

I have a `Steps` component that is a wrapper.
And I have multiple `Step` components that goes into `Steps` component as children.

In my `Steps` component, I want to create a new children array that only consists of `Step` components. I simply want to ignore everything else. Meanwhile showing some warning on the console that *anything other than `Step` component child will be disregarded*, would be fine but whatever, that is not important at this point.

```
<Steps>
  <Step>Hello</Step> // should be rendered
  <div>Please ignore me</div> // should be ignored
  <Step>How are you?</Step> // should be rendered
</Steps>
```

The problem is, I am working with TypeScript and I cannot access to `child.type` as many other answers in other questions suggest.

[image]

Error is as follows:

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
```

When I hover over `child`, it shows this:

```
(parameter) child: React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal
```

Could you point me to the right direction please? How can I check the type of `child` and return a new `children` array with only those that is instance of `Step`?

Comment: Found  similar issue, check it once
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366077/only-allow-children-of-a-specific-type-in-a-react-component

Comment: I saw that one. TypeScript gives me an error when I try to check `child.type` but the accepted answer is not using TypeScript in that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

When I apply `React.Children.Map` on `props.children`, `child` is expected to be of type `string | number | boolean | {} | React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>> | React.ReactNodeArray | React.ReactPortal`.

After applying `React.isValidElement(child)` filter on child, it removes all the non-ReactElement items from the union type and leaves `React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>> | React.ReactPortal` behind. After that, `type` property appears on the `child` value.