# React render specific children

Tags: reactjs, children

I have looked through other peoples questions relating to this but cant find a suitable answer. I would like to pass children to a component and then pull out the specific children where I want them, most examples I have seen just have the children render in the same place.

My component looks something like this -

```
<ParentComponent>

<ChildOne/>
<ChildTwo/>

<ParentComponent/>
```

When I log the props.children inside the parent component I get an array which contains both children as objects. is there a simple way to pull out the specific child where I need it such as `{props.children.ChildOne}` at the moment I am using `props.children[0]` which isn't ideal as we will be passing the children dynamically
in the future and the array length may change.

As always any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a ton of elements here, to check the type of a child element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366077/only-allow-children-of-a-specific-type-in-a-react-component

Comment: Apparently, you need to use [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) and the comparison `child.type === (<ChildOne/>).type` or `child.type === ChildOne`.

Comment: All of which seems to be production ready (works after minimisation).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact situation and needs, it might make more sense to pass child components as props than using the special `children` prop. Then you can render them whichever way you like.

```
<ParentComponent childOne={ChildOne} childTwo={ChildTwo} />
...
const ParentComponent = ({ childOne, childTwo }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {childOne}
      <div>
        {childTwo}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But knowing your exact scenario would help a lot with conceptualising the best way to implement this. Perhaps you can refactor your code to avoid passing an array of children like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the `displayName` property for the child components and then use the `displayName` in the parent to find the specific children from children list and place them where you want it to be.

```
// define displayName for each component, it can be any string
// You can set the displayName for any react component before exporting as shown 
// below

const ChildOne = (props) => { return (<div> Child One </div>)}
ChildOne.displayName = "ChildOne";
export default ChildOne;

const ChildTwo = (props) => { return (<div> Child Two </div>)}
ChildTwo.displayName = "ChildTwo";
export default ChildTwo;
```

Now in parent component you can filter out the specific child by using their displayName.

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {

const getChildByDisplayName = (displayName) => {
  const child = React.Children.map(props.children, (child => {
     // you can access displayName property by child.type.displayName
     if (child.type.displayName === displayName) return child;
     return null;
  }))
  return child;
}    

return (
 <div>
   {/* You can change the order here as per your wish*/}
   {getChildByDisplayName("ChildOne")}
   {getChildByDisplayName("ChildTwo")}
 </div>
)
}
```

That's it, Now even if you put `ChildTwo` before `ChildOne` like below example, parent component will still render the `ChildOne` first and then `ChildTwo` because we have defined order in parent.

```
<ParentComponent>

 <ChildTwo/>
 <ChildOne/>

<ParentComponent/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the [`ReactChildren`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) API I was mentioning is useless here.

You can do something like this instead:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ChildOne } from './YourFile';

export function ParentComponent({children}) {
  return children.find(child => child.type === ChildOne)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the key seems simpler:

**whatever is using the parent component:**

```html
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildOne key="title"/>
    <ChildTwo key="picture"/>
<ParentComponent/>
```

**parent component:**

```js
export default function ParentComponent(props: any) {
    const title = props.children.find((o: any) => o.key === 'title')
    const picture = props.children.find((o: any) => o.key === 'picture')
    return <div>
        <jumbobox>
            {title}
        </jumbobox>
        <fancyframe>
            {picture}
        </fancyframe>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to control the Child Components being passed to `ParentComponent` through state/props/redux store management in the component containing `ParentComponent` and its `children`.

But to have the solution as per your use case, we can avoid using `children` prop and use our defined prop on `ParentComponent`.

```
<ParentComponent
    components={[
     {key: 1, component: <div>Hello</div>}
    ]}
/>
```

So, we can now filter from the key.

Checkout this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/crazy-pond-tgg2w?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Ideally, We should not build logic by reading properties from React's internals.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to want to use numbers to refer to its component. So a `key` isn't a good idea I think.